# Sinatra/static assets

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I cloned a sinatra app https://github.com/trivektor/Backbone-Hangman with a file set up like you see in the image below. In the terminal, I ran the  `ruby hangman.rb` commandbut I got the error

```
`require': no such file to load -- sinatra/static_assets
```

Would static_assets refer to the images and css in the public folder? Is static_assets the sinatra way of including those files?  Can anyone explain what might be the problem?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
gem install sinatra-static-assets
```

fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like that example needs the [sinatra-static-assets](https://github.com/wbzyl/sinatra-static-assets/) gem.